# Xamarin.Forms ImageGallery Displaying Images rows in two columns

Tags: xaml, listview, binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I need to display 10 images in 2 columns. I saw an [ImageGallery.cs in XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageGallery) but its incomplete, the renderers are 404.

The Images are in a `List<Image>` which contains `string imageURL` and other few properties. I thought about putting two `ListView` side by side, but that just seems stupid.

**I'm using ViewModel, hence I want to bind the list and not add them one by one**

Answer (score 0):

XLabs ImageGallery is working fine (links are outdated):

- Android:
  https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/ImageGallery/ImageGalleryRenderer.cs
- iOS:
  https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/ImageGallery/ImageGalleryRenderer.cs

BTW: It's better to use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: Actually I'm using `ObservableCollection` as I'm loading the items as I scroll down. My bad, didnt say it.

Also, I'm developing for WP8.1 too, didnt see any link (even outdated) for its renderer so I didnt pursue that component much.
Is there any renderer for WP8.1?

Comment: It shouldn't be too complicated to write your own renderer for Windows. Just combine `Image`, `ISupportIncrementalLoading`, `GridView` and `Panorama` http://www.xamlplayground.org/post/2012/06/10/Metro-Incrementally-load-GridView-and-ListView-with-ISupportIncrementalLoading.aspx